# Find the value of the service

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

The VAT amount charged for a certain service was $60.  If 12% is charged as VAT what is the value of the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\text{ the original value}$.

Let's translate: The taxes are \$60. This **is** 12% **of** the original value.

> 60 $\underbrace{\text{[ is ]}}_{\text{EQUALS}}$ 12 percent $\underbrace{\text{[ of ]}}_{\text{TIMES}}$ x $\ \ \ \longrightarrow \  \ \ $ $60 = 0.12 \cdot x$

Now solve for x.

Comment: so 1% is 5 so 100% = 5*100= $500 Correct?

Comment: Does 0.12*500 equal 60? If so then you have it.

Comment: Yes 0.12*500 equals 60 , Thanks